# Tables and tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have the following code:

```
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{|c||p{4cm}||p{3cm}|}
\hline
\textsc{\textbf{Nombre}} & \textsc{\textbf{Ancho de banda con compresión}} & \textsc{\textbf{Ancho de banda sin compresion}} \\ \hline
H.261 & 40 Kbits/s & 2 Mbits/s \\ \hline
H.263 & 64 Kbits/s & 583.9 Mbits/s \\ \hline
H.263p & 64 Kbits/s & 583.9 Mbits/s \\ \hline
H.264 & 64 Kbits/s & 960 Mbit/s \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

My problem is that I don't know why it give me this output: 
[image: latex]

Why the yellow zone appears?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: set one column `X`

Comment: The `tabularx` tries to fill the whole width, regardless whether there are columns or not. (And as touhami said: use `X` for at least one column)

Comment: Off-topic: There is no bold-smallcaps font combination in the Computer Modern font family; that's why the screenshot is showing bold rather than bold-smallcaps glyphs in the header row. If you must have the bold-smallcaps combination, you will need to use a different font family, such as Times Roman.

Comment: There really is no point to using tabularx there it is designed to adjust linebreaking and you never want automatic linebreaking in data tables, just use a normal tabular

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - There's line-breaking going on in two of the header cells. :-)

Comment: @Mico that's why I added "automatic":  headers are delicate things best to break them manually normally:-)

Answer (score 6):

I can't understand why you use `\tabularx` if you than not use `X` column type ... If you like to have table width equal to `\textwidth`, than exploit `tabularx` capabilities!

Anyway, see if the following solutions is what you looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

    \usepackage{makecell,tabularx}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\scshape}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X||X||S[table-format=3.2]@{}X<{Mbits/s}|}
                                    \hline
\thead{Nombre} 
        & \thead{Ancho de banda\\ con compresión} 
                     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{
                       \thead{Ancho de banda\\ sin compresion}} 
                               \\   \hline
H.261   & 40 Kbits/s &   2   & \\   \hline
H.263   & 64 Kbits/s & 583.9 & \\   \hline
H.263p  & 64 Kbits/s & 583.9 & \\   \hline
H.264   & 64 Kbits/s & 960   & \\   \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{document}
```

In it I stole font issues from Mico answer, employ `makecell` package for seting column headers and for numbers in the third column use `S` columns from `siunitx`.

Alternative solution, as rswponse to Mico comment:

[image]

In this case the code is a bit modified:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

    \usepackage{makecell,tabularx}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\scshape}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|@{\quad}l||
           >{\centering\arraybackslash}X||S[table-format=9.2]@{}l<{Mbits/s\qquad\qquad}|}
                                    \hline
\thead{Nombre}
        & \thead{Ancho de banda\\ con compresión}
                     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{
                       \thead{Ancho de banda\\ sin compresion}}
                               \\   \hline
H.261   & 40 Kbits/s &   2   & \\   \hline
H.263   & 64 Kbits/s & 583.9 & \\   \hline
H.263p  & 64 Kbits/s & 583.9 & \\   \hline
H.264   & 64 Kbits/s & 960   & \\   \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: If you're going to center-set the material in the header row, I think the material in the data columns should be center-set as ewll (rather than be set (mostly) flush-left).

Comment: @Mico, you have right. To my answer I added example as you suggest.

Answer (score 3):

You ask for a tabular length of `\textwidth` but do not adpate the size of the column. You could use `X` to do so. In `tabularx`, `X` will expand the column to fit the required size.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{|X||p{4cm}||p{3cm}|}
\hline
\textsc{\textbf{Nombre}} & \textsc{\textbf{Ancho de banda con compresión}} & \textsc{\textbf{Ancho de banda sin compresion}} \\ \hline
H.261 & 40 Kbits/s & 2 Mbits/s \\ \hline
H.263 & 64 Kbits/s & 583.9 Mbits/s \\ \hline
H.263p & 64 Kbits/s & 583.9 Mbits/s \\ \hline
H.264 & 64 Kbits/s & 960 Mbit/s \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The `X` instead of `c` is better for two reasons: alignment and of course using `tabularx` features (+1)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to providing at least one type-X column in a `tabularx` environment, you should also

- use a font family that actually provides bold-smallcaps glyphs (Computer Modern does not), and
- not use full justification in narrow columns, as doing so will almost certainly create unacceptably large gaps between words; instead, use ragged-right mode in narrow columns
- strive for a more "open" look of the table, by (i) not using any vertical bars, (ii) getting rid of the majority of horizontal lines, and (iii) using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package for the remaining few horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

% Use a font family that provides bold&smallcaps glyphs
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}     
\usepackage{booktabs,ragged2e}

% ragged-right version of "p" column type
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}} 

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{X P{3cm} P{3cm}}
\toprule
\textsc{\textbf{Nombre}} & 
\textsc{\textbf{Ancho de banda con compresión}} & 
\textsc{\textbf{Ancho de banda sin compresión}} \\
\midrule
H.261 & 40 Kbits/s & 2 Mbits/s \\ 
H.263 & 64 Kbits/s & 583.9 Mbits/s \\ 
H.263p & 64 Kbits/s & 583.9 Mbits/s \\ 
H.264 & 64 Kbits/s & 960 Mbit/s \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks you, this works.
I will put in use all of your advices.