# How can I prevent a line break in math inside of a table?

Tags: tables, formatting

I have this section of TeX that describes a table

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.142\linewidth}|p{0.142\linewidth}|p{0.142\linewidth}|p{0.142\linewidth}|p{0.142\linewidth}|p{0.142\linewidth}|p{0.142\linewidth}|}
\hline
\sloppy Angle ($\theta$) deg \newline $\Delta\theta=\pm0.5$ & \sloppy Time (t) s \newline $\Delta t\nolinebreak=\pm0.11$ & \sloppy Time (t) s \newline $\Delta t\nolinebreak=\pm0.11$ & \sloppy Time (t) s \newline $\Delta t\nolinebreak=\pm0.11$ & \sloppy Time (t) s \newline $\Delta t\nolinebreak=\pm0.11$ & \sloppy Time (t) s \newline $\Delta t\nolinebreak=\pm0.11$ & \sloppy Time (t) s \newline $\Delta t=\pm0.11$ \\ \hline
0.00                         & Did not move      & Did not move      & Did not move      & Did not move      & Did not move      & Did not move      \\ \hline
15.0                         & 3.95              & 3.90              & 3.73              & 3.93              & 3.86              & 3.87              \\ \hline
30.0                         & 2.77              & 2.84              & 2.74              & 2.80              & 2.81              & 2.79              \\ \hline
45.0                         & 2.66              & 2.71              & 2.69              & 2.67              & 2.65              & 2.68              \\ \hline
60.0                         & 3.39              & 3.23              & 3.26              & 3.34              & 3.32              & 3.31              \\ \hline
75.0                         & 5.01              & 5.00              & 4.91              & 4.91              & 4.95              & 4.96              \\ \hline
90.0                         & Did not move      & Did not move      & Did not move      & Did not move      & Did not move      & Did not move      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

When I build this with pdflatex on Windows 10, I get this output.

[image: TeX Output]

What I want to be output is this:

[image: Desired Output]

What I want is the Time (t) and s to be on different lines, and \delta t and \pm0.11 to be on the same line in the first row of the table. Also, I would like "Did not move" to be on the same line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE. if equation is longer than width of `p{<width>}` cell, than you cant prevent. You have three possibilities: (i) make cell width larger, (ii) use smaller font or (ii) change cell type to `l` or `c` or `r`.

Comment: as you see in your image the line break happens _after_ = not before  so you have the  nolinebreak in the wrong place, but just preventing the break doesn't really help unless you make the expression smaller or the table wider.

Comment: please always post a complete (small) document so that people can reproduce the problem. For example here the problem will only arise for certain values of `\linewidth` so we have to guess...

Comment: The break means there is not enough space for keeping everything on the same line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use `\mbox{}` in order to avoid the line break. In addition - it has nothing to do with your question - I think that `Time (t) s` is not a "correct" format. I would use `Time $t$ in s` instead since `t` is a variable and should be italic (meaning in math mode). The "in" is also just a recommendation.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true,margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.142\textwidth}|p{0.142\textwidth}|}
\hline
% Cell 1
    Angle $\theta$ \newline 
    in deg  \newline 
    \mbox{$\Delta\theta=\pm0.5$} 
& 
% Cell 2 
    Time $t$ \newline 
    in s \newline 
    \mbox{$\Delta t=\pm0.11$}
    \\ \hline
% Data
0.00 & Did not move   
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Even if you make the cell **way too small** (e. g. 0.042\textwidth) then you still have no line break:

[image]

Maybe have a look at [Package tabularx (Error: Missing number, treated as zero.)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354063) and the links that [@Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) recommends in his comment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My bad - I didn't read the question thorough enough.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried again :)

Comment: Thanks for the fix! I'll italicize the t, but I won't add "in". The format that we're using for our papers is very specific in how it wants the data formatted.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to avoid repeating information; moreover spelling out “Did not move” would make the table overlong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\newcommand{\dnm}{{DNM}}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=2.0]
  *{6}{S[table-format=1.2]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
{Angle (deg)} & \multicolumn{6}{c@{}}{Time (s)} \\
{$\theta$} & {$t_1$} & {$t_2$} & {$t_3$} & {$t_4$} & {$t_5$} & {$\bar{t}$}\\
\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-7}
{$\Delta\theta=\pm0.5$} & \multicolumn{6}{c@{}}{$\Delta t=\pm0.11$} \\
\midrule
 0 & \dnm & \dnm & \dnm & \dnm & \dnm & \dnm \\
15 & 3.95 & 3.90 & 3.73 & 3.93 & 3.86 & 3.87 \\
30 & 2.77 & 2.84 & 2.74 & 2.80 & 2.81 & 2.79 \\
45 & 2.66 & 2.71 & 2.69 & 2.67 & 2.65 & 2.68 \\
60 & 3.39 & 3.23 & 3.26 & 3.34 & 3.32 & 3.31 \\
75 & 5.01 & 5.00 & 4.91 & 4.91 & 4.95 & 4.96 \\
90 & \dnm & \dnm & \dnm & \dnm & \dnm & \dnm \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize\dnm: Did not move}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very cool! Nice.

Comment: Holy crap, I love the way this looks. I'll have to check with my teacher to see if this would be a good format.

Comment: What do the parameters that follow `\begin{tabular}` do?

Comment: @Artillect `S[table-format=1.2]` means a column with aligned numbers with one digit in the integral part and two in the fractional part.

Comment: @egreg If I wanted to use this same formatting for a 2 column table with text only, what would I need to change?

Comment: @Artillect Use standard l c r columns

Answer (score 3):

Since the page layout of your document is not known, the following solution is based on guessing, that is close to what is obtained by us of `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` package.

With packages `siunitx` (for units and column formatting), `tabularx` (for simple formatting of table with equal width columns) and `makecell` for column headers, I obtain the following table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% <-- this solve problem with breaking equation into two line
\usepackage{makecell,tabularx}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|S[table-format=2.2]|
                         *{6}{S[table-format=1.2]|}
                            }
    \hline
{\thead{Angle ($\theta$)\\ $\Delta\theta=\SI{\pm0.5}{\degree}$}}
        &   {\thead{Time ($t$)\\ $\Delta t=\SI{\pm0.11}{s}$}}
                &   {\thead{Time ($t$)\\ $\Delta t=\SI{\pm0.11}{s}$}}
                        &   {\thead{Time ($t$)\\ $\Delta t=\SI{\pm0.11}{s}$}}
                                &   {\thead{Time ($t$)\\ $\Delta t=\SI{\pm0.11}{s}$}}
                                        &  {\thead{Time ($t$)\\ $\Delta t=\SI{\pm0.11}{s}$}}
                                                &   {\thead{Time ($t$)\\ $\Delta t=\SI{\pm0.11}{s}$}}  \\
    \hline
0.00    & \mcx{Did not move}    
                & \mcx{Did not move}    
                        & \mcx{Did not move}      
                                & \mcx{Did not move}
                                        & \mcx{Did not move}
                                                & \mcx{Did not move}    \\ \hline
15.0    & 3.95  & 3.90  & 3.73  & 3.93  & 3.86  & 3.87                  \\ \hline
30.0    & 2.77  & 2.84  & 2.74  & 2.80  & 2.81  & 2.79                  \\ \hline
45.0    & 2.66  & 2.71  & 2.69  & 2.67  & 2.65  & 2.68                  \\ \hline
60.0    & 3.39  & 3.23  & 3.26  & 3.34  & 3.32  & 3.31                  \\ \hline
75.0    & 5.01  & 5.00  & 4.91  & 4.91  & 4.95  & 4.96                  \\ \hline
90.0    & \mcx{Did not move}
                & \mcx{Did not move}
                        & \mcx{Did not move}
                                & \mcx{Did not move}
                                        & \mcx{Did not move}
                                                & \mcx{Did not move}    \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note: default font size in `\thead` is `\footnotesize`.

**Edit:**
Reducing page margins to 25mm and `\tabcolsep` from default 6pt to 3pt, andd increase `thead` font size to small and `\arraystretch` to 1.2, the table become:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,
            margin=25mm]{geometry}% <-- this solve problem with breaking equation into two line
\usepackage{makecell,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}X|}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\linespread{0.8}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|S[table-format=2.2]|
                         *{6}{S[table-format=1.2]|}
                            }
    \hline
{\thead{Angle ($\theta$)\\ $\Delta\theta=\SI{\pm0.5}{\degree}$}}
        &   {\thead{Time ($t$)\\ $\Delta t=\SI{\pm0.11}{s}$}}
                &   {\thead{Time ($t$)\\ $\Delta t=\SI{\pm0.11}{s}$}}
                        &   {\thead{Time ($t$)\\ $\Delta t=\SI{\pm0.11}{s}$}}
                                &   {\thead{Time ($t$)\\ $\Delta t=\SI{\pm0.11}{s}$}}
                                        &  {\thead{Time ($t$)\\ $\Delta t=\SI{\pm0.11}{s}$}}
                                                &   {\thead{Time ($t$)\\ $\Delta t=\SI{\pm0.11}{s}$}}  \\
    \hline
0.00    & \mcx{Did not move}    
                & \mcx{Did not move}    
                        & \mcx{Did not move}      
                                & \mcx{Did not move}
                                        & \mcx{Did not move}
                                                & \mcx{Did not move}    \\ \hline
15.0    & 3.95  & 3.90  & 3.73  & 3.93  & 3.86  & 3.87                  \\ \hline
30.0    & 2.77  & 2.84  & 2.74  & 2.80  & 2.81  & 2.79                  \\ \hline
45.0    & 2.66  & 2.71  & 2.69  & 2.67  & 2.65  & 2.68                  \\ \hline
60.0    & 3.39  & 3.23  & 3.26  & 3.34  & 3.32  & 3.31                  \\ \hline
75.0    & 5.01  & 5.00  & 4.91  & 4.91  & 4.95  & 4.96                  \\ \hline
90.0    & \mcx{Did not move}
                & \mcx{Did not move}
                        & \mcx{Did not move}
                                & \mcx{Did not move}
                                        & \mcx{Did not move}
                                                & \mcx{Did not move}    \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Note (2)**: when columns width is enough large then equation is not broken and prevent its breaking with with `\mbox{$<equation>$}` is surplus. This fix can cause new problem in table: if cell is narrower then column width -- equation spill-out on the right side as is shown in *Dr. Manuel Kuehner* answer. my conclusion: fix for your table is make columns' width larger ...

Comment: the space between the two lines of "did not move" is excessive.  this would be better treated as a paragraph rather than as a two-line table entry.

Comment: yes, this degrade table looks. With further increase table width (with smaller page margins) the all texts are fitted in one line. See edit of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Still not pretty but

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.142\linewidth}|p{0.142\linewidth}|p{0.142\linewidth}|p{0.142\linewidth}|p{0.142\linewidth}|p{0.142\linewidth}|p{0.142\linewidth}|}
 \hline
 \centering\small Angle~($\theta$)\,deg \\ $\Delta\theta=\pm0.5$ &
 \centering\small Time (t)\,s \\ $\Delta t=\pm0.11$ &
 \centering\small Time (t)\,s \\ $\Delta t=\pm0.11$ &
 \centering\small Time (t)\,s \\ $\Delta t=\pm0.11$ &
 \centering\small Time (t)\,s \\ $\Delta t=\pm0.11$ &
 \centering\small Time (t)\,s \\ $\Delta t=\pm0.11$ &
 \centering\small Time (t)\,s \\ $\Delta t=\pm0.11$ \tabularnewline 
\hline
0.00                         &
 \centering Did not move      &
 \centering Did not move      &
 \centering Did not move      &
 \centering Did not move      &
 \centering Did not move      &
 \centering Did not move      \tabularnewline
 \hline
15.0                         & 3.95              & 3.90              & 3.73              & 3.93              & 3.86              & 3.87              \\ \hline
30.0                         & 2.77              & 2.84              & 2.74              & 2.80              & 2.81              & 2.79              \\ \hline
45.0                         & 2.66              & 2.71              & 2.69              & 2.67              & 2.65              & 2.68              \\ \hline
60.0                         & 3.39              & 3.23              & 3.26              & 3.34              & 3.32              & 3.31              \\ \hline
75.0                         & 5.01              & 5.00              & 4.91              & 4.91              & 4.95              & 4.96              \\ \hline
90.0                         & \centering Did not move      & \centering Did not move      & \centering Did not move      & \centering Did not move      & \centering Did not move      & \centering Did not move      \tabularnewline
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\centering` makes it indeed prettier .

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner not much:)